# Mercurial: Problem converting Windows cvs repository to mercurial

Tags: mercurial, cvs

I’m trying to convert an existing Windows CVS repository to Mercurial and getting the following response  and error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>hg convert c:\users\jeff\webs\shelter-cvs\shelter

assuming destination shelter-hg
initializing destination shelter-hg repository
connecting to :local:c:\cvs
abort: unexpected response from CVS server (expected "Valid-requests", but got 'E cvs [server aborted]: c:\\cvs: no such repository\n')
```

Here’s the background:

- The repository was created with
  TortoiseCVS so I believe it’s
  actually cvsnt.
- I can properly checkout from the
  repository using either the command
  line or the TortoiseCVS gui, so I
  think it is set up correctly.
- I'm trying to convert a working copy,
  not the repository itself
- I’m running Windows 7, 64-bit
- I’ve installed TortoiseHG and enabled
  the convert extension.

Comment: can you properly checkout from the working copy, or only the actual repository ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I think the checkout is from the repository.  Is there a way to checkout from the working copy?  How do I do that?  Just specify the working copy location instead of the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author said:

> I'm trying to convert a working copy,
>   not the repository itself

That makes what you're doing not possible.  You need access to the repo, not to a checkout of it.  CVS checkouts (unlike mercurial checkouts) don't include full history.  The best you can do with just a checkout is to import a snapshot or two.

Comment: I thought that I needed to run convert on a checkout, not the repository in order to convert cvs to mercurial.  I DO have access to the repository.  It's located at c:\cvs\shelter, but when I modify the convert command to:  
    hg convert c:\cvs\shelter
I get the error:  No such file or directory: c:\cvs\shelter\CVS\Root.

Comment: With HG Convert, it NEEDS to look at a working directory, but it also needs access to the CVSROOT that local directory is going to point at.
http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_CVS

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and resolved it by changing the CVSROOT (environment variable) from a local folder to using :pserver, like this:

```
:pserver:username@computername:/CVS
```

This works on CVSNT, or at least it did for me.

Comment: The next issue you'll probably encounter on Windows is this: http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2117

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of doing exactly what you are trying to do.  I assume you have installed cvsps and configured the convert extension in your .hgrc correctly?

Your command though for conversion is likely the problem.  You are specifying the *path* to the module you want to convert, not the module name itself.

Try the following:

> c:
>   cd \users\jeff\webs\shelter-cvs\
>   hg convert shelter

The above will create the Hg repository as "shelter-hg".  You could alternatively specify where you'd like to have the Hg repository go with:

> cd \users\jeff\webs
>   mdir hg_repo
>   cd shelter-cvs
>   hg convert shelter ..\hg_repo\shelter

Hope this helps,

mG.

Comment: still doesn't work for me; I get exactly the same "no such repository" error which doesn't seem to make sense.  I did a fresh checkout from the repository, which worked, so it clearly exists!

I checked out to c:\users\jeff\desktop where it created the directory 'shelter.'  Then I did:  cd c:\users\jeff\desktop\shelter.  Then I ran: hg convert shelter and it gave the error.  If I first switch into c:\users\jeff\desktop\shelter and then execute the hg convert command, it says 'shelter doesn't look like dvs checkout.'

Comment: Did you test to see if the cvsps command works?  I had to fudge with it for a bit before hg convert would work, since hg convert depends on cvsps.

I think you want to first CD to c:\users\jeff\desktop, then try "cvsps shelter".  If it works, it should start spitting out the commit history for the shelter module.  If not, then hg convert won't work.

Additionally, I think you should be running the "hg convert shelter" command also from the "desktop" directory, not from within the shelter directory.

Comment: hmm.  cvsps command not working, so I guess it's not installed in windows.  I did install it in cygwin, but when I cd /cygdrive/c/users/jeff/desktop and then cvsps shelter, I get:  'cannot determine CVSROOT.'

Comment: BTW: I've moved away from "hg convert" and am on to "cvs2hg".

    http://vc.gerg.ca/hg/cvs2svn/file/tip/README.cvs2hg

An interesting thread in the Hg mail list on recent conversion efforts:

    http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2010-January/029668.html

Comment: Also note that CVS is not CVSNT.  If you have been using CVSNT, you'll need to stick with CVSNT tools.